# Test Unit Jasmine e Karma Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, angular6, karma-jasmine

I'm doing unit testing on angle 6, I'm having trouble testing this branch, I use it to observe how big the screen is to decide how many columns I'll display

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-rdesp-waiting-approval',
  templateUrl: './rdesp-waiting-approval.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rdesp-waiting-approval.component.scss'],
  animations: fuseAnimations

})
export class RdespWaitingForApproval implements OnInit  {
constructor(
    @Inject(ToastrService) private toaster: ToastrService,
    private _profileService: ProfileService,
    private _service: ApprovalsService,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    public _matDialog: MatDialog,
    private _approvalsService: ApprovalsService,
    private  media: ObservableMedia
) {
   this.watcher = media.subscribe((change: MediaChange) => {
      this.activeMediaQuery = change ? `'${change.mqAlias}' = (${change.mediaQuery})` : '';
          if ( change.mqAlias == 'xs') {      
           this.displayedColumns = ['job' ,'name', 'totalValue'];
          }else{
            this.displayedColumns = ['internalId','DateOfPublication', 'alias', 'job', 'name','totalValue'];
      }
    });

  
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you tell us more About what `media` is? Is it a, service?

Comment: Class internalizes a MatchMedia service and exposes an Subscribable and Observable interface.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in an answer to your other question, you need to mock the ObservableMedia service and return something that allows testing.  As a reminder, here is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53934411?file=app%2Fmy.component.spec.ts) I set up to demonstrate this.  In the Stackblitz I only have the ObservableMedia tested, not all the other dependency injections.

Here are two specs from that StackBlitz:

```
it('should have 3 columns in mat table when changeMqAlias === "xs"', () => {
    component.changeMqAlias = 'xs';
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.displayedColumns).toEqual(['job', 'name', 'totalValue']);
});
    it('should have 6 columns in mat table when changeMqAlias !== "xs"', () => {
    component.changeMqAlias = 'xl';
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.displayedColumns.length).toEqual(6);
});
```

I hope this helps.